# How to use assigns in a test with nested form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, integration-testing

How can I use assigns in a nested situation?

As part of a test I make a post with valid information:

```
post organizations_path, organization: { org_name: "abcdef",
                                         phone: "0123456",
                    members_attributes: [email: "uniqueemail@uniqu.br",
                                         username: "solida",
                                         password: "foobar",
                                         password_confirmation: "foobar"] }
```

This posts to a nested form where an organization can have multiple members.

The test continues:

```
organization = assigns(:organization)
member = assigns(:member)
```

This works for organization but it doesn't work for member (it doesn't assign anything for member). Other forms I tries all didn't work:

```
member = assigns(:organization.member)
member = assigns(:organization.members_attributes)
member = assigns(:members_attributes)
```

How can I use assigns for member as well in this nested case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigns simply allows you to access an instance variable (`@organization` in your case.) I assume this is populated with an instance of `Organization` in your controller, so you access the members the same way you would if you were accessing them directly on that instance, i.e.:

```
member = assigns(:organization).members.first
```

If your `Organization` has many members, you'll need to use `first`, to get a single one (even if you only created one.)